# How can I index only active user accounts in a user index?

Tags: search

I'm setting up [Search API Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) to make a user search on my site. On this site, when a user account is cancelled, we keep the data but block the account (set the status to non-active). This is necessary to prevent abuse of the system, but I want to eliminate the risk that data from these accounts would be exposed in Solr search, so I am looking for a way to index only active users.

I've been digging around but couldn't find any way to configure the index to not add blocked users. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Search API has a built-in filter for excluding unpublished nodes, but not users.

So [here's a patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2491175).